# Как правильно вывести таблицу

Tags: html, css

Я через сервлет вывожу информацию из MySQL в виде таблицы (name и surname). Он работает правильно, но когда выводится таблица он без линии между ячейками. Как можно туда добавить линии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
<div class="ShowAllStudent">
                <h1>All Students</h1>
                <table>
                    <%
                        ArrayList<Student> students = (ArrayList<Student>) request.getAttribute("students");
                        for (Student student : students) {
                    %>
                    <tr>

                        <td><%=student.getSurname()%></td>

                        <td><%=student.getName()%></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="servlet.MyServlet?actionname=RemoveStudent&id=<%=student.getId()%>">X</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно например изменить тег table

```
<table border="1">
```

или с помощью css

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
```

или можно стиль применить на ячейку

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black;">
```

или если требуется то можно поставить border только с одного края ячейки
например, если отделить имя от "удаления"

```
<td style="border-right: 1px solid black;">
<%=student.getName()%>
</td>
```

Comment: спасибо сработало, но как сделать чтобы между ними были линии между именем фамилией и удалением)

Comment: поправил немного свой ответ... это в общем-то уже html и css

Comment: Спасибо но там он не отображает

Comment: Спасибо а как можно сделать так чтобы сверху было написано name и surname и delete. Я просто сам только начинаю учится)

Comment: Имеешь ввиду заголовок в таблице? Ну, тогда просто вначале отдельную строку в таблицу добавляешь <tr><td>name</td><td>SurName</td><td>Delete</td></tr> сразу же после тега <table>

Comment: да спасибо) вам)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Приятного кодинга! )))